# How do I create a Table from a For loop?

Tags: plotting, infinite-loop, sow-reap, table

I've been trying to create a table that has the % of the cycle of a sample and the module of acceleration for the first 100 values, but I don't know how to create it. Here's the code:

I have imported the data from an A table in excel which has the time and acceleration. There are 241 values.

```
Inc2 = (A[[241, 1]] - A[[1, 1]])/100 (*Percentage of my cycle*)
Reap[
  For[i = 1; n = 0, i <= 100,  i++; n = n + Inc2]
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please load data (10 entries perhaps) and present a minimal example along with the desired outcome to get a focused reply. Thanks.

Comment: If you use Reap, you need Sow. And Reap need an enclosing barcket.

Comment: Do you have to use a `For` loop?  Seems like more functional constructs can do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
Subdivide[A[[1, 1]],A[[241, 1]],100]
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit cumbersome, but something like this might get you close to what you want without using a procedural loop.

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
ic2[aLast_, aFirst_] := (aLast - aFirst)/100
(ic2[#[[1]], #[[2]]] + Position[data, #][[1, 1]]) & /@ data
```

Probably more elegantly done with `NestList` or `FoldList` or even `Table`.

(I haven't had my coffee yet this morning).

Answer (score 1):

1. Wolfram strongly recommends that user variable names ***not*** start with a capital letter so that those variables will not overshadow Mathematica values now or in the future.
2. I suggest reading Forman S. Acton's [*Real Computing Made Real*](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486152936.html) to undertand why I used multiplication instead of accumulative addition. Hint: computer floating numbers almost never represent real numbers exactly,
3. Mathematica is definitely not a Fortran or C-like language

The first line generates a faked version of your code.
The second and third lines shows the first and rows of the faked data,

```mma
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {241, 2}]; 
First[a]
Last[a]
inc2 = Subtract @@ a[[{-1, 1},1]]
({#1, #1*inc2} & ) /@ Range[0, 100]
TableForm[%]
```

The matching results"

```
{0.10746548833059077, 0.08695916608169596}
{0.6458285821946712, 0.3832483598318581}
0.5383630938640804
{{0, 0.}, {1, 0.5383630938640804}, {2, 1.0767261877281609}, 
  {3, 1.6150892815922413}, {4, 2.1534523754563217}, 
  {5, 2.691815469320402}, {6, 3.2301785631844826}, 
  {7, 3.768541657048563}, {8, 4.3069047509126435}, 
  {9, 4.845267844776724}, {10, 5.383630938640804}, 
  {11, 5.921994032504885}, {12, 6.460357126368965}, 
  {13, 6.998720220233046}, {14, 7.537083314097126}, 
  {15, 8.075446407961206}, {16, 8.613809501825287}, 
  {17, 9.152172595689368}, {18, 9.690535689553448}, 
  {19, 10.228898783417527}, {20, 10.767261877281609}, 
  {21, 11.30562497114569}, {22, 11.84398806500977}, 
  {23, 12.382351158873849}, {24, 12.92071425273793}, 
  {25, 13.459077346602012}, {26, 13.997440440466091}, 
  {27, 14.53580353433017}, {28, 15.074166628194252}, 
  {29, 15.612529722058333}, {30, 16.15089281592241}, 
  {31, 16.689255909786493}, {32, 17.227619003650574}, 
  {33, 17.765982097514655}, {34, 18.304345191378737}, 
  {35, 18.842708285242814}, {36, 19.381071379106896}, 
  {37, 19.919434472970977}, {38, 20.457797566835055}, 
  {39, 20.996160660699136}, {40, 21.534523754563217}, 
  {41, 22.0728868484273}, {42, 22.61124994229138}, 
  {43, 23.149613036155458}, {44, 23.68797613001954}, 
  {45, 24.22633922388362}, {46, 24.764702317747698}, 
  {47, 25.30306541161178}, {48, 25.84142850547586}, 
  {49, 26.379791599339942}, {50, 26.918154693204023}, 
  {51, 27.4565177870681}, {52, 27.994880880932183}, 
  {53, 28.533243974796264}, {54, 29.07160706866034}, 
  {55, 29.609970162524423}, {56, 30.148333256388504}, 
  {57, 30.686696350252586}, {58, 31.225059444116667}, 
  {59, 31.763422537980745}, {60, 32.30178563184482}, 
  {61, 32.84014872570891}, {62, 33.378511819572985}, 
  {63, 33.91687491343707}, {64, 34.45523800730115}, 
  {65, 34.993601101165225}, {66, 35.53196419502931}, 
  {67, 36.07032728889339}, {68, 36.60869038275747}, 
  {69, 37.14705347662155}, {70, 37.68541657048563}, 
  {71, 38.22377966434971}, {72, 38.76214275821379}, 
  {73, 39.30050585207787}, {74, 39.838868945941954}, 
  {75, 40.37723203980603}, {76, 40.91559513367011}, 
  {77, 41.453958227534194}, {78, 41.99232132139827}, 
  {79, 42.53068441526236}, {80, 43.069047509126435}, 
  {81, 43.60741060299051}, {82, 44.1457736968546}, 
  {83, 44.684136790718675}, {84, 45.22249988458276}, 
  {85, 45.76086297844684}, {86, 46.299226072310915}, 
  {87, 46.837589166175}, {88, 47.37595226003908}, 
  {89, 47.914315353903156}, {90, 48.45267844776724}, 
  {91, 48.99104154163132}, {92, 49.529404635495396}, 
  {93, 50.06776772935948}, {94, 50.60613082322356}, 
  {95, 51.144493917087644}, {96, 51.68285701095172}, 
  {97, 52.2212201048158}, {98, 52.759583198679884}, 
  {99, 53.29794629254396}, {100, 53.83630938640805}}
TableForm[{{0, 0.}, {1, 0.5383630938640804}, 
   {2, 1.0767261877281609}, {3, 1.6150892815922413}, 
   {4, 2.1534523754563217}, {5, 2.691815469320402}, 
   {6, 3.2301785631844826}, {7, 3.768541657048563}, 
   {8, 4.3069047509126435}, {9, 4.845267844776724}, 
   {10, 5.383630938640804}, {11, 5.921994032504885}, 
   {12, 6.460357126368965}, {13, 6.998720220233046}, 
   {14, 7.537083314097126}, {15, 8.075446407961206}, 
   {16, 8.613809501825287}, {17, 9.152172595689368}, 
   {18, 9.690535689553448}, {19, 10.228898783417527}, 
   {20, 10.767261877281609}, {21, 11.30562497114569}, 
   {22, 11.84398806500977}, {23, 12.382351158873849}, 
   {24, 12.92071425273793}, {25, 13.459077346602012}, 
   {26, 13.997440440466091}, {27, 14.53580353433017}, 
   {28, 15.074166628194252}, {29, 15.612529722058333}, 
   {30, 16.15089281592241}, {31, 16.689255909786493}, 
   {32, 17.227619003650574}, {33, 17.765982097514655}, 
   {34, 18.304345191378737}, {35, 18.842708285242814}, 
   {36, 19.381071379106896}, {37, 19.919434472970977}, 
   {38, 20.457797566835055}, {39, 20.996160660699136}, 
   {40, 21.534523754563217}, {41, 22.0728868484273}, 
   {42, 22.61124994229138}, {43, 23.149613036155458}, 
   {44, 23.68797613001954}, {45, 24.22633922388362}, 
   {46, 24.764702317747698}, {47, 25.30306541161178}, 
   {48, 25.84142850547586}, {49, 26.379791599339942}, 
   {50, 26.918154693204023}, {51, 27.4565177870681}, 
   {52, 27.994880880932183}, {53, 28.533243974796264}, 
   {54, 29.07160706866034}, {55, 29.609970162524423}, 
   {56, 30.148333256388504}, {57, 30.686696350252586}, 
   {58, 31.225059444116667}, {59, 31.763422537980745}, 
   {60, 32.30178563184482}, {61, 32.84014872570891}, 
   {62, 33.378511819572985}, {63, 33.91687491343707}, 
   {64, 34.45523800730115}, {65, 34.993601101165225}, 
   {66, 35.53196419502931}, {67, 36.07032728889339}, 
   {68, 36.60869038275747}, {69, 37.14705347662155}, 
   {70, 37.68541657048563}, {71, 38.22377966434971}, 
   {72, 38.76214275821379}, {73, 39.30050585207787}, 
   {74, 39.838868945941954}, {75, 40.37723203980603}, 
   {76, 40.91559513367011}, {77, 41.453958227534194}, 
   {78, 41.99232132139827}, {79, 42.53068441526236}, 
   {80, 43.069047509126435}, {81, 43.60741060299051}, 
   {82, 44.1457736968546}, {83, 44.684136790718675}, 
   {84, 45.22249988458276}, {85, 45.76086297844684}, 
   {86, 46.299226072310915}, {87, 46.837589166175}, 
   {88, 47.37595226003908}, {89, 47.914315353903156}, 
   {90, 48.45267844776724}, {91, 48.99104154163132}, 
   {92, 49.529404635495396}, {93, 50.06776772935948}, 
   {94, 50.60613082322356}, {95, 51.144493917087644}, 
   {96, 51.68285701095172}, {97, 52.2212201048158}, 
   {98, 52.759583198679884}, {99, 53.29794629254396}, 
   {100, 53.83630938640805}}]
```